# Determine if function is being set to variable or simply executed in Python

Tags: python

I have a function that both prints the output and returns that output, ie.

```
def simple_function():
    x = "hello world"
    print(x)
    return x
```

This function is meant to be used in a notebook and the problem is that if a function is not set to a variable, the notebook does the print and then also displays the returned object, so visually the output appears to be duplicated, something like this:

```
simple_function()

"hello world"
Out[93]: "hello world"
```

In my actual function, the output could print thousands of lines, and when it gets duplicated it looks very unappealing. What I want to know is if it's possible for me to determine through the function itself if the output is being set to a variable so that I can just return nothing and only print the output. Open to other ideas as well, if it achieves what I'm going for.

The notebooks I'm using are DataBricks notebooks on Azure.

Comment: This seems wrong. The function should just return the data. If the caller wants it printed, they can use `print(simple_function())`

Comment: The print function does print, irregardless of what calls it... The default behavior of IPython is to **also** print the function result, if not captured separately

Comment: I think in the function you could just remove the `return` statement if you don't want it to be set to any variables.

Comment: @Barmar : But in that way, they could do `variable=simple_function()` and the OP does not want it to be set into a variable.

Comment: If you don't want them to assign the result to a variable, why are you returning it in the first place?

Comment: So what I want is the option to return to a variable. If they set it to a variable, don't print at all, if they don't then do print. I agree this feels wrong, but I want to check.

Comment: If you can edit the function's source, return the `print` and print outside of the function; otherwise just assign to a variable. You might use `_ = simple_function()` to indicate that the value is not used. Or add a parameter `verbose` or `do_print` to the function.

Answer (score -2):

Just pass a variable to set it to, like this:

```py
def simple_function(r=false):
    x = "hello world"
    if r:
        return x
    else:
        print(x)

simple_function() # hello world (printed)

variable = "previous string"

variable=simple_function(true) # hello world (stored)
```

Comment: @user3124181 : I think I remember that in Python all variables are passed by reference.  Let me check again to be sure.

Comment: @user3124181 : See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python for reference (all variables are passed by reference, so it will update the real variable)

Comment: @LakshyaRaj passing variables by reference means that you could mutate a mutable object (e.g. append to a `list`) within the function, but you can't assign an entirely different object to the variable (that would be possible with pointers but we don't have those in Python). In this case, when you're assigning `var=x`, `var` becomes a local variable whose lifetime will end when you exit the scope of the function. After returning from the function, `var` will again become the variable from the outer scope. I recommend you to try running the code and printing the value of `val` at various points.

Comment: @Czaporka : OK I changed my answer.